# Pasting a line within dat files in multiple directories except for dat files with a certain name

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, echo

Pasting a line within dat files in multiple directories except for dat files with a certain name.

Here's the code I've got so far.

```
for file in */*; do
if [ $file != "NoEdit.dat" ]
then
echo 'Configuration' >> $file
fi
done
```

Any ideas on how to exclude files that go by the name of "NoEdit.dat"? 
I've been trying to implement !(NoEdit.dat) and "if" arguments. 
I am a complete newbie to programming in general, any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Using the find command worked.

```
find */* ! -name 'NoEdit.dat' -exec sh -c 'echo "Configuration" >> {}' \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code achieves what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory='/folder/'
mkdir -p /tmp/
find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' | grep -e ".dat" | grep -v "NoEdit.dat" > /tmp/holder && directoryEscaped="$(echo "$directory" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')" && sed -i -e "s/^/$directoryEscaped/" /tmp/holder
while read -r line; do
filename="$line"
echo 'Configuration' >> "$filename"
done < /tmp/holder
exit 0
```

All you need to do is to provide the variable "directory" with the folder path to be searched. Basically, the code creates a temporary file with the file paths of all files that don't match the name you provided, and then it echos the string on each one of them (at the end of each file).

**Edit**: I edited the code to search for and change only .dat files

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it very much! I happened to solve the problem in my ways via using the "find" command, I'll put it down here incase it comes in use:

`find */* ! -name 'NoEdit.dat' -exec sh -c 'echo "Configuration" >> {}' \;`

Comment: You're welcome! I just noted on your code (and on my code) that the script would add "Configuration" to all files not named 'NoEdit.dat' (including, for example, .txt files). I corrected my answer to look for and change only ".dat" files as the question required.